# ¿Como actualizo un bool en un archivo .h?

Tags: c++, variables

Tengo el siguiente código en el archivo .cpp (No el main):

```
    switch (opc) {
    case 1:

        while (jugando) {
            //limpiar pantalla
            h.limpiar();

            //elimina scroll bar
            h.nosc();

            //dibuja marco
            h.draw();

        } 

            break;
}
```

Solo dejo el primer case ya que es el único relevante. Luego, en la función h.draw(), que lo único que hacer es dibujar un marco con gotoxy, tengo el llamado

```
this->jugando = false;
```

Luego de esa linea, sale de la función y vuelve al while, luego de esto debería cerrar el programa ya que jugando = false, sin embargo se vuelve a correr una y otra vez.

El `bool` jugando lo tengo declarado en la clase del archivo .h, no sé si debería incluir todo el archivo, pero la declaración es sencilla:

```
bool jugando;
```

Apreciaría mucho la ayuda.

Comment: separarlo en .h y .cpp es indiferente, tu a un programa no tienes que verlo como un conjunto de archivos, en el caso de OOP debes verlos como un conjunto de objetos que interactuan, en consecuencia en tu caso el bool del archivo .h es lo mismo que el bool del .cpp, asi que yo pienso que el error esta en otro lado, si deseas ayuda provee un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

> Luego de esa linea, sale de la función y vuelve al while, luego de esto debería cerrar el programa ya que jugando = false, sin embargo se vuelve a correr una y otra vez.

Revisa con detenimiento el código:

```
while (jugando) {
    //limpiar pantalla
    h.limpiar();

    //elimina scroll bar
    h.nosc();

    //dibuja marco
    h.draw();
}
```

Dices que `h.draw()` llama a `this->jugando=false`, pero en el `while` no estás consultando el estado de `h.jugando`, sino de `jugando`, es decir, una variable que o bien está declarada a nivel de la función que contiene el `while` o bien es una variable global.

Como bien sabes (o vas a aprender ahora mismo), en C++ puedes tener varias variables con el mismo nombre siempre y cuando su ámbito no sea exactamente el mismo:

```
int a;

namespace test
{
  int a;
}

struct POO
{
  int a;
};

int func()
{
  int a;
}
```

En tu caso el problema que tienes es que la variable que actualizas no es la misma cuyo valor estás comprobando en el `while`. La solución no la tengo muy clara porque no hay apenas código y no se si es posible verificar el estado de `h.jugando` directamente o si bien hay que hacerlo mediante algún *getter*. El código debería quedar más o menos así:

```
while (h.get_jugando()) {
```

Donde `get_jugando()` lo sustituyes por el mecanismo dispuesto para leer el estado de `h.jugando`.